# Do there exist pro-$p$ groups with finite quotients of non $p$ power order?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, profinite-groups, pro-p-groups

We define a pro-$p$ group to be a projective (i.e. inverse) limit of $p$-groups.

My question is exactly as stated in the title:

> If a subgroup $H$ of a pro-$p$ group $G$ has finite quotient, must $|G/H|$ be some power of $p$?

If we restrict ourselves to open subgroups, then I believe this is the case because the open subgroups in the projective limit form an open basis of the identity. However for general finite index subgroups I am not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No such subgroup exists. Pro-$p$ groups with the second definition (i.e. inverse limit of discrete, finite $p$-groups) can be easily shown to be equivalent to the first definition:

$$G/N\cong P$$

where $N$ is open, normal and $P$ is a finite $p$-group.

How so? Since $N$ is normal it is the union of some open subgroups from a basis of open normal subgroups around the identity, however we know that if

$$G=\varprojlim_{i\in I} G_i$$

with each $G_i$ a discrete, finite $p$-group, then such a basis is given by

$$U_i=\pi_i^{-1}(G_i)$$

If

$$N=\bigcup_{i\in J\subseteq I} U_i$$

select any $i_0\in J$ then we have a surjective homomorphism:

$$G/U_{i_0}\to G/N$$

with kernel $N/ U_{i_0}$, hence $G/N$ is the homomorphic image of a finite $p$-group, and is hence a $p$-group.

**(Edit)** For I think, following the comments, I should include the nitty gritty of the reduction to the closed case since there's enough confusion to merit it. Throughout we use $|\cdot|$ for the order of an element and of a subgroup, understood in the generalized sense of profinite groups (i.e. supernatural numbers)

> The basic idea:  just use the Lagrange theorem for profinite groups.
>
> The problem:  indices are only defined for **closed** subgroups.

If $|A|=p^nm$ with $(p,m)=1$ and select $a\in A$ such that $|a|\big| m$, which is possible by Cauchy's theorem. Name the projection map $\pi:G\to G/N\cong A$ (first isomorphism theorem) is surjective, we may select a lift $\stackrel{\sim}{a}\in G$, and by definition $\left|\pi\left(\stackrel{\sim}{a}\right)\right|=|a|$, we have just changed our context from $A$ to a subgroup of order coprime to $A$--namely $\langle a\rangle$--so that we may assume that $p\not\big| |A|$ rather than the weaker condition $|A|\ne p^n$. Denote by $H$ the closure of $\langle\stackrel{\sim}{a}\rangle$ in $G$. Then $|\stackrel{\sim}{a}|=m$ in $H/H\cap N$, which is finite because $N\cap H$ is clearly relatively open in $H$.

Since $H$ is closed, $m\big||H|$, and by Lagrange $|H|\; \bigg|\; |G|$. However $(m,p)=1$ and the only prime dividing $|G|$ is $p$, hence $m=1$, so that $\langle a\rangle\le A$ is the trivial subgroup and $|A|=p^n$.

Comment: Doesn't the universal property go the other way?

Comment: But doesn't this only work for normal subgroups?

Comment: @Alexander You're assuming that $A$ is the image of $G$ under a homomorphism, and kernels of homomorphisms are **always** normal...

And even so, the open normal subgroups still form a fundamental set of neighborhoods for the topology around the identity, that's how the inverse limit topology is defined.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I guess I meant open subgroups. Like what if the subgroup is not open but still finite index?

Comment: @Alexander that's impossible, profinite groups are compact, and if $U\subseteq G$ is open then we note that

$$\bigcup_{g\in G} gU$$

is an open cover of $G$, so it has a finite subcover. i.e. $G=U\cup g_1U\cup\ldots\cup g_nU$

i.e. $U$ has finite index, since these are all the left cosets of $U$, and they are finite in number.

If the group is finite index, then note that it is the complement of the union of the other left cosets, which are all closed, hence it is open. In fact $U$ is finite index, closed iff $U$ is open.

Comment: @Alexander you might argue:  "what if $N$ is not closed?" But I counter with the fact that we give the discrete topology to the quotient, so that it is, in particular, Hausdorff, which is the same as saying the subgroup by which we quotiented is closed.

Comment: @Adam The last assertion is cheated. You implicitly claim that every finite index subgroup of a profinite group is open. This in not true --- see EX 4.2.12 in the book by Ribes-Zalesskii. For finitely generated profinite groups this is true but a deep theorem by Nikolov-Segal. The error in your above argument is that you assume that G/N be a Hausdorff space.

Comment: @user59363 I'm well aware of the pathological problems that can happen with strange topologies (see the recent comments for the details). The point is that the statement is purely algebraic, so I may as well pick a topology on the target which makes things convenient (the same is true for the infinitude of primes proof) especially as taking closures isn't really a problem, in fact that's exactly what happens in the general case. At the same time I think you are right that I skipped a bit too much; easily remedied.

Comment: @Alexander Since it seems there's enough confusion I added the details for the non-open case. It's not at all different from the open case (where everything follows from Lagrange's theorem) you just look at closures everywhere instead.

Comment: @Adam Your proof only works in case $H$ is clopen where it is indeed Lagrange's Theorem, but to my understanding the question asks if this is true in general (for example if $H$ is dense as in EX 4.2.12 in Ribes-Zalesskii) --- this is answered affirmatively in Prop. 4.2.3 in Ribes-Zalesskii.

Comment: @user59363 I think you should take a look at mine again:  $H$ is the closure of the arbitrary group, all closures are closed. It does not also need to be open, Lagrange's theorem holds for all closed groups, the order is simply a supernatural number. See Serre's *Galois Cohomology* if you're not familiar with this. (It's somewhere between pages 3 and 5 if I recall correctly)

Comment: @Adam If you take the closure $\bar H$ of a finite index subgroup $H$ of $G$ then it may be that $G=\bar H$, so the index $[G,\bar H]=1$ does not give you any information about the index $[G:H]$. I understood the original post as asking about finite index subgroups which are not open (and therefore not closed).

Comment: @user59363 yes, for general $H$, that may be true, but that isn't really relevant in this proof, in particular I cannot see how it affects anything at all.

Comment: @user59363 I perused the proof in the book you mention. It's basically the exact same thing I've stated. ($1$) They choose a prime $p|m$ instead of $m$ itself, but that doesn't materially change anything, I use Cauchy's theorem to produce $m$, so I can only guarantee there's a prime anyways, ($2$) their $x$ is my $\stackrel{\sim}{a}$, and ($3$) they take the closure, just as I do. And all the other details look to be exactly the same, modulo what they call things and minor differences in the amount of detail at each key step.

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware of the profinite Lagrange theorem. This clears up a lot of my confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Look at Proposition 4.2.3 in the book by Ribes-Zalesskii, the whole section 4.2. will be interesting for you. Edit: the question is answered affirmatively there.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Edward I agree, the post does not provide an answer, but the cited Proposition does. I did not require any clarification from the author nor did I intend to critisize the original post. To the contrary, I consider this an interesting question.

Comment: @user59363 can you edit to provide more explicit support for the affirmative? Your answer may be accurate but is not approachably informative.